# find all words in list/file that begin/ends with a specific prefix/suffix

Tags: python, prefix, suffix

The below code gives the words which begin/ends with a specific prefix/suffix:

```
string_list = [line.strip() for line in open("file.txt", 'r')]
for word in string_list:
    if word[-1] == "a":
        print word

        
string_list = [line.strip() for line in open("file.txt", 'r')]
for word in string_list:
    if word[0] == "fi":
        print word
```

How can I optimize it to be real fast on huge data?

Comment: You might want to post this to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `word` is a string, then `word[0] == "fi"` does not do what you think it does.

You can instead use `startswith` and `endswith` to check for *multicharacter* suffixes and prefixes.

```
string_list = open("file.txt", 'r')

for word in string_list:
    if word.startswith("fi") or word.endswith('a'):
        print word
```

---

To pass the suffix/ prefix as a parameter to your script, have a look at [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Comment: I updated it to x = filter(lambda s: s.startswith("fi"), string_list)

Comment: how to use both sys.argv[] as well as argparse?

Answer (score 0):

If you need speed, you could simply use [GREP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep), which is written in a lowlevel language and is bound to be faster than a python loop by leaps and bounds.

It is also portable and runs just fine on Linux/Windows/OSX/...

Comment: grep can be faster, but i want to be fast enough by using py